# Google OAuth not working in React with Safari Mobile iOS

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth, mobile-safari

Reproducible Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-nash-4xdw98?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { GoogleLogin } from "@react-oauth/google";
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from "@react-oauth/google";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>This does not work on Mobile Safari</h1>
      <h2>Unless I turn off "Content Blockers" which is enabled by default</h2>
      <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="841329522756-eduphp40v3ut3r66puadfk1jgheoppva.apps.googleusercontent.com">
        <GoogleLogin
          onSuccess={(resp: any) => {
            console.log(resp);
          }}
          onError={() => {}}
        />
      </GoogleOAuthProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The Login Button does not show up at all for Safari Mobile on iOS. Unless I turn off "Content Blockers" which is enabled by default. How do I fix this?

Update:
The Documentation says that  (the button that does not work in Safari), produces a "CredentialResponse" object for onSuccess.

It gives you the option to create a custom button using useGoogleLogin, however the onSuccess function does not give me a  CredentialResponse, which is whats required for my Django Login to work.

This seems like a pretty common pattern in React, but a massive problem given so many people use the default iOS Browser...

[image: With Content blocking on]
[image: With Content Blocking off]